# Parsing Out DL Information that was scanned into asp text box using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good Morning...I am working on a kiosk program and one of the options is to allow people to insert their Driver License to check in...I am wanting to parse the information from the Driver License...I have been able to achieve 90% of this but am having a little trouble getting the last part...which is the DOB...I am still new to C# and learning as I go...any help is greatly appreciated...below is the code I am using...

**HTML**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" autofocus ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" MaxLength="1000"></asp:TextBox>
```

**C#**

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string s = TextBox1.Text;
  int beglastname = s.IndexOf("^");
  int endlastname = s.IndexOf("$", beglastname + 1);
  string lastname = s.Substring(beglastname + 1, endlastname - beglastname - 1);

  int begfirstname = s.IndexOf("$");
  int endfirstname = s.IndexOf("^", endlastname + 1);
  string firstname = s.Substring(endlastname + 1, endfirstname - begfirstname - 1);

  int begaddress = s.IndexOf("^", endlastname + 1);
  int endaddress = s.IndexOf("^", endfirstname + 1);
  string address = s.Substring(endfirstname + 1, endaddress - begaddress - 1);

  int begdob = s.IndexOf("=", begaddress + 1);
  int enddob = s.IndexOf("?", endaddress + 1);
  string dob = s.Substring(endaddress + 1, enddob - begdob - 1);

  File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\test\dl_test.txt", firstname + " " + lastname + " " + address + " " + dob);

  //MessageBox.Show(firstname + " " + lastname + " " + address);

}
```

**The information that is being parsed from the text box is as follows:**

card inserted ^Smith$John^123 Main^=19780101?

**The results are as follows:**

John Smith 123 Main =1978010

**The results should be as follows:(to be able to switch the DOB info into the format MM-DD-YYYY would be great also...but not necessary at this time)**

John Smith 123 Main 19780101

Why is the = sign showing and why is the last number of the DOB being cut off...

This is prob a very simple fix...but one that I am having trouble with...thank you again for your help...

I edited the below code and it works:

```
    int begdob = s.IndexOf("=", begaddress + 1);
  int enddob = s.IndexOf("?", endaddress + 1);
  string dob = s.Substring(endaddress + 2, enddob - begdob - 1);
```

However...if my string is the below:

card inserted ^Smith$John^1123 Main^459846=895519780101?

I am having difficulty parsing out the DOB...the below is what I am getting:

John Smith 1123 Main 59846=895519

What I need from this string is below:

John Smith 1123 Main 19780101

Thanks again for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is not working is the following code:

```
string dob = s.Substring(endaddress + 1, enddob - begdob - 1);
```

First off, your looking at only one character past the end of the address, when there's a 2nd padding character of '='. Secondly, since the DOB field is always 8 characters, you should be doing the substring backwards from the padding character 8 characters in length.

So:

```
string dob = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("?", endaddress + 1) - 8, 8);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help...it works like a champ!!! I appreciate you taking the time to help me out...Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line of code:

`string dob = s.Substring(endaddress + 1, enddob - begdob - 1);`

if you look at your string `^Smith$John^123 Main^=19780101?` you can see that `endaddress + 1` is actually referring to the start index of the `=`. What you want to do based off of your code... would be to do this  `string dob = s.Substring(begdob + 1, enddob - begdob - 1);`

That will get you want you want.